# Does the usage of "let know" makes sense?

Tags: usage, pronouns, let

I've read the message:

> Kindly let know about the pay per product descripton

I'm in doubt if it is ok to use **let know** without a pronoun like **let me know**,does this sound natural or can be used in any context?

Comment: You are right, it's wrong.

Comment: It's a jarring shorthand typical of sms communications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Let know" is not idiomatic.  You are correct that you do need to use *some* subject, but it doesn't have to be a pronoun.

> Let **grandma** know her favorite TV show is on.
>
> Let **the cat** know it's time for dinner.
>
> Let **all the good little children, in every country, all over the world** know that Santa is coming.

Comment: what about "Let it be known" it gives the meaning of "let everyone knows" right?

Comment: @Zorkind  The point of the passive voice is to avoid specifying the subject.  So "Let it be known" is ambiguous, so you have to judge from the context -- but, yes, by default it means "let everyone know".

Comment: "Need to use some subject" - the word "subject" doesn't seem appropriate, since the word after "let" is an object.  (We'd always say "let him know", not "let he know".)

Answer (score 0):

### Object

You can't use the phrase "let know" without a direct object.  You have to say "let us know", "let them know", "let me know", "let the supervisor know", etc - not just "let know" on its own.  It is transitive.

### Passive

It is rare (and almost always unidiomatic) to use "let" in the passive.  You can say "She let me try", but you can't say "I was let try (by her)".

Similarly, you can say "She let me know", but you should avoid "I was let know".

Interestingly, "let go" works in the passive, at least colloquially.  "He was let go" means "he was dismissed from employment".